# send data to server in real time

Tags: android, multithreading, tcp, client-server

I ma trying to make a remote mouse app for android (to control the mouse on a PC from a phone, via TCP). On the clientside (android), I implemented the OnTouchListener in the UIThread, but the client socket and the IO runs in another thread. The server receives the coordinate, but only one time, even if the client is sending in a while(true) loop and Im moving my finger over the display of the phone. It should permanently send the most recent coordinates, not only the first one.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
private ServerSocket ss;
private Socket socket;
TextView tv;
String x, y;
private static final int SERVERPORT = 444;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.3";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    RelativeLayout l = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myView);
    l.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

class Worker implements Runnable{

    PointF point;
    public Worker(PointF point) {
        this.point = point;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress adress = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket("192.168.1.3", SERVERPORT);
            BufferedWriter obf = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

                obf.write(point.x+" "+point.y);
                obf.flush();
                obf.close();


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
   ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();

    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        x=String.valueOf(event.getX());
        y=String.valueOf(event.getY());
        tv.setText(x+" + "+y);
        PointF point = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
        executor.execute(new Worker(point));
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: you can use threadpool with queue for this.

Comment: how does a threadpool work? what is it good for?

Comment: refer this link http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor.html

Comment: so I edited it, added a blockingQueue and I already can send the the to the server, but only one time - the server receives point, even if the client sends in a while(true). I Dont understand this.

Comment: no, it receives only the first coordinate - when I first touch the display. But it shoult permanently get the most recent coordinate

Comment: remove the while infinite loop from onTouch .

Answer (score 0):

You can simply implement this ...

```
class Worker implements Runnable{
    PointF point;
    public Worker(PointF point) {
        this.point = point;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {

        //send pointf to server here 
    }

}
   ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();

    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        PointF point = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
        executor.execute(new Worker(point));
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I checked with local server and it is working for me .

Comment: gave up tcp and made it with udp, but anyway, thanks. how do I mark the qoustion as solved? :P